# Ошибка в условном операторе

Tags: php

Я делаю такую штуку:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM startpoke WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'");

if(life > 0 ){

$res = mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `life`=`life`-3 WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
}
else
{
echo "бе";
}
```

У меня `life` больше нуля и оно выводит мне "бе". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изучайте основы.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM startpoke WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if($row['life'] > 0 ){

$res = mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `life`=`life`-3 WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
}
else
{
echo "бе";
}
```

Comment: спасибки =)

Answer (score 0):

Не `life`, а `$life`.

Comment: Да он вообще неправильно код написал.

Comment: Ну неизвестно же, что там в `life` находится, может, это не весь код. Не факт, же что `life` - это строка из БД.

Comment: Согласен, что неплохо было бы самые азы почитать, чем спрашивать реализацию каждой строчки.

Comment: Ну на сколько мне известно, то ему общими силами тут всю игру пишут )))

Comment: Классный язык ПХП !